# ¿Como hacer una relación en Mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo es problema, intento relacionar un viaje con el usuario que publicó ese viaje para cuando desee mostrarlo por lista salga en un lado *`Creado por Juan`* por ejemplo.

Este es mi código:

trip.model.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TripSchema = new Schema({
    lat: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },
    long: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

export default mongoose.model('Trip', TripSchema);
```

user.model.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { isEmail } from 'validator';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

/**
 * JWT Config
 */
import JWTConfig from '~config/jwt';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: [ isEmail, 'El correo electrónico ingresado no es válido' ],
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

UserSchema.pre('save', async function( next ){
    let user = this;
    try {
        let salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync( JWTConfig.salt );
        let hash = await bcrypt.hashSync( user.password, salt );
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    } catch( e ){
        return next( e )
    }
})

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Esos son mis modelos, y parece andar bastante bien y tiene el field de relación como los ejemplos que he visto.

Entonces hago la siguiente consulta:

```
let trips = await Trip.find().populate('User');
console.log( trips[0] )
```

Y el resultado que veo por consola es:

```
{
  _id: 5df8eb236f61c20d055ac869,
  lat: 1235,
  long: 1235,
  user_id: 5df57b546441b407f87ee45b,
  createdAt: 2019-12-17T14:50:11.283Z,
  updatedAt: 2019-12-17T14:50:11.283Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Muestra solo la ID del usuario que creó el viaje y tengo entendido que debería mostrar user: { ...datos del usuario... } en vez de la id... No sé que estoy haciendo mal, por favor ayúdenme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolví.

Primeramente el parámetro que se pasa en el `.populate` debe pasar el nombre del field. Yo tengo:

```
user_id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
```

Entonces mi `populate` debería ser: `.populate('user_id')`

Tambien al final sería: `.exec();`

Quedaría asi:

```
let trips = await Trip.find().populate('user_id').exec();
```

Con eso anduvo. Muchos quizá lo sabían, yo pues encontré esta solución y bueno la comparto.

Answer (score 0):

En trip.model.js ,después de este código

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Agrega esto más, que te sirve para utilizar el modelo.

```
const User = mongoose.model('User');
```

Avisas si era por eso.

Y si no prueba con esto, que se trata de modificar el metodo populate de esta manera.

```
let trips = Trip.find({}, function(err, trips) {
    User.populate(trips, {path: "user"},function(err, trips){
        return trips
    }); 
});
console.log( trips[0] )
```

Comment: No hace nada, incluso también después lo agregué a ref: User, sin comillas pasandole la variable pero nada, todo igual.

Comment: Eso segundo tampoco, sale igual, user_id: objectID

Comment: Intenté cambiar todo de user_id a user, pero igual

Comment: En la segunda en vez de return trips, prueba con console.log(trips), y vé que sale.

Comment: Resolví, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @Jonathan cual era el problema.

Comment: Que solamente salia la ID del creador, no sus datos